# What is the typical AI approach for solving blackjack?

Tags: python, game-ai, algorithm-request, monte-carlo-methods

I'm currently developing a blackjack program. Now, I want to create an AI that essentially uses the mathematics of blackjack to make decisions.

So, what is the typical AI approach for solving blackjack?

It doesn't have to be language-specific, but if it will help with an answer, the language I plan to use to do this would be Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blackjack is usually modelled using Monte Carlo (MC) Methods. There is a lot of literature on MC methods which is interesting on its own right but [here](https://math.dartmouth.edu/theses/undergrad/2014/Vaidyanathan-Thesis.pdf) is a paper describing how MC is applied to Blackjack. There is also a good description on page 110 of the [Introduction to Reinforcement Learning](http://people.inf.elte.hu/lorincz/Files/RL_2006/SuttonBook.pdf).

Good luck!